# Analytics - Which layer?

Tags: android, architecture, analytics

Very open architectural question.

I have an Android offline app.
In one of the actions user can change a configuration, in my specific case it is the day of the forecast.
So to do that, the flow is this:

- Activity on click event;
- Preferences View Model;
- Preferences Business;
- And finally persisted on the persistence layer;

The actual effect will happen in parallel (no important for my question).

My questions are:
Where is the best place to add the analytics track?
What exactly should I be considering when positioning my analytics track events?

Just in case, this is the app I'm talking about: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pozzo.apps.travelweather

Thank you

Comment: When I am implementing Analytics in my applications I put all Analytics trackers into presenters (MVP). Only small activities / fragments are covered with the analytics because for the static activities I do not like to overengineer things. The problem with my approach is that sometimes I need to deal with some boilerplate, to cover some of the cases. I just decided to do so to be consequent in the whole application. In your case, all depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Analytics is part of the domain layer, so It should ideally be kept in the domain layer. Often projects have analytics in the view layer (ViewControllers, activities or fragments or ViewModels). This leads to inconsistency and analytics calls are often fired from views or view models, controllers etc.

Therefore, it is ideal to keep analytics inside UserCase/interactor classes, these are often re-usable classes, which makes logging easier with less duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of clean architecture analytics it's business layer, so it should be implemented in Interactor/Use case, but I think it's not so bad to keep analytics in a view, because it's simplest way.